# filtering rows based on counts of variables across multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataset that looks like this:

```
d <- read.table(text = "
X1    name   var1  var2  var3
A1    A1        0     9     0
A3    A3        0     7     0
A4    A4        0    11     0
A5    A5        0     7     0
A6    A6        0     8     0
D     D         0    11     0
IN    A5        0     0    11
IN    IN        0    11     0 ", header = TRUE)
```

I'd like to filter out rows when the count of variables in both X1 + name is >=3 giving this:

```
X1 name var1 var2 var3
A5   A5    0    7    0
IN   A5    0    0   11
IN   IN    0   11    0
```

the furthest I've got is:

```
    d%>% 
    group_by (X1,name) %>% 
    filter(n() >=3)
```

but I know I'm missing something here as it doesn't work.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't understand from your example what you are trying to do. What exactly does "count of variables in both X1 + name is >=3" mean? Why is the first row filtered out? What variables are you counting?

Comment: Do you mean to keep rows, which together (over the entire dataframe) yield at least three out of four possible combinations of two given levels (e. g. AA, AB, BA, BB) for X1 and name?

Comment: I think the goal is to keep any row for which the value of `X1` and/or the value of `name` appear more than once in that respective column.

Answer (score 3):

```
d %>%
  add_count(X1, name = "X1_count") %>%
  add_count(name, name = "name_count") %>%
  filter(X1_count + name_count >= 3)


  X1 name var1 var2 var3 X1_count name_count
1 A5   A5    0    7    0        1          2
2 IN   A5    0    0   11        2          2
3 IN   IN    0   11    0        2          1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- table(c(d$X1, d$name)) >= 3
keep <- names(x[x])

d |>
  filter(X1 %in% keep | name %in% keep)
```

Or in base R:

```
subset(d, X1 %in% keep | name %in% keep)
```